# jQuery trigger function from code loaded by append

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there anyway to call a function or trigger an event from html loaded from an append() call?  I have a  tag  It is filled when a user licks on a list of things like this. in my index.html I have something like this:

```
function doThis(someData) {
  $.get("/url/"+someData, function(htmlFromServer) {
    $("#something").append(htmlFromServer);
  });
}

function doSomething(moreData) {
  alert(moreData);
}
```

I want to be able to do something like this in the returned html

```
<div>
  <p>This is an important message</p>
<script>
 doSomething("this message is different for each page");
</script>
</div>
```

I want to be able to call one function, but depending on what is returned, I alert a different message.  I want the front end to call one endpoint,  but what happens next is dynamic. I don't want to do a huge if block in my doThis(), or worse, a function for each possibility that "someData"  may have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this to work by defining all my functions in a javascript file and import like usual.

I then make a decision on the back end that all of the possible html that is returned by the jQuery get() call, has a hidden form field with the id of "x"  and the value being the function name I want to call after the .append(htmlFromServer) is done.

So i have this function in a .js file defined int the head as usual. I then do this:

```
$.get("/url/"+someData, function(htmlFromServer) {
  $("#myDiv").append(htmlFromServer).append(function() {
    var functionToCall = $("#x").val(); // x is the id of the element
    window[functionToCall]();
  });
}
```

And I now have a generic way of handling different data depending on the server response without a big if block.

Answer (score 0):

You could pass a function to `doThis`. You also probably meant to concatenate the `someData`.

```
function doThis(someData, cb) {
  $.get("/url/" + someData, function(htmlFromServer) {
    $("#something").append(htmlFromServer);
    cb()
  });
}
```

```
doThis('somepath', () => console.log('append successful'));
```

Comment: Thanks for the concatenate, fixed.  But your solution only calls doThis after the append.  I need to be able to change the message depending on what comes back from the get() call.

Comment: You can pass whatever you want as the callback. For the example in the code in the answer, given a path of `somepath`, you can then log `append successful`. You could also do, eg `doThis('someOtherPath', () => console.log('got some other path'))`